# Is the set of analytic functions equal to the set of polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion, complete-spaces, analytic-functions

Taylor's theorem and the Taylor series give us an equivalence between analytic functions and polynomials. For example, $C^\omega \ni e^x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} \in \mathbb{P}$, where $C^\omega$ is the set of all complex analytic functions and $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of all complex polynomials. Since, by definition, an analytic function has a polynomial (Taylor series) which converges to the function, does that imply that $C^\omega = \mathbb{P}$? Or is it not correct to say that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n \in \mathbb{P}$?

Comment: Polynomials are defined to be finite sums of powers of $x$. So $e^x$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: If $\mathbb{P}_N$ is the set of polynomials of degree at most $N$, then what is $\mathbb{P}_\infty = \mathbb{P}$? Is it still the set of polynomials of any finite degree only? I think the notation in the book I'm looking at is what's confusing me.

Comment: A non terminating Power series is not a polynomial.